# Why is my Pygame window only displaying for only a few seconds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to PyGame (and python in general) and I am just trying to get a window to pop up. That's all I'm after for now. Here's my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')
```

I am using Python 3.7.0 in Pycharm and PyGame 1.9.4.

Answer (score 3):

Following Python's PyGame [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-python-3-part-1-intro/), your next step is to start a while loop to handle the game frames:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    # Determine FPS (frames-per-second)

crashed = False

# Game loop
while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        print(event)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Okay. That was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @codeInjection You are welcome. You may click the check mark next to the answer to mark this question as resolved if this helped

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to first put it inside a loop (so it refreshes whatever is inside it), that way it stays on until something alters the condition of that loop.

```
# Event loop (HERE YOU PUT IT).
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do apologize though and please excuse my noobish antics here. I guess I'm just not understanding where my code would fit into that while loop. I copied and pasted your code into mine and it didn't change anything. Would you mind rewriting it in such a way that my code is included?

Comment: Haha, years ago I used Pygame, though I do knew that loop was missing. Also, you didn't needed to simply copy/paste it. @bunbun answer is what you need.